# AWS API Gateway messing up response: { "message": "Internal server error" }

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

There's a lot of questions out there pertaining to "lambda" but I haven't touched that in my life, so it probably isn't relevant to this question.

All I've done so far is import a swagger json spec into AWS API Gateway and try my best to configure it to connect to my REST api.

My issue here is that when I try calling the API gateway endpoint through the test console, everything works as expected.

[image]

But then why I try querying the same endpoint from outside AWS like any end user, I get this nondescript 500 response.

[image]

The nifty thing is that since I own the backend service, I can see the logging, which clearly indicates that a successful 200 response was returned (which should be the json response shown in the first screenshot).

[image]

So now I know that it's AWS's fault that I'm getting a 500. But I'm honestly not sure what the issue could be.

Here are all relevant configuration screens for this particular endpoint.

#### Method Request

[image: Method Request]

#### Integration Request

[image]

#### Integration Response

[image]

#### Method Response

[image]

If there's any screen/setting I didn't provide that would be helpful, just let me know.

### TLDR, api gateway endpoint works in online console ui, but not in real life

Comment: You need to follow this guide to enable at least error logging for API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html Then you should be able to trigger this error again, and find the actual API Gateway error message in those logs.

Comment: You're probably using the AWS Lambda proxy integration for API Gateway and your response isn't compliant with the necessary payload response format.

Comment: cloudwatch integration just has to be a 15 step process right? lol @MarkB this is one of the things I think google does a lot better

Comment: @Dunedan that was my first thought as well, but then it should be failing when testing through the AWS console also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follows @MarkB's advice and linked API Gateway to an IAM role with permissions to write to Cloudwatch and then here's the kicker: you have to redeploy the stage to jumpstart Cloudwatch (this is actually very poorly documented, aws).

And when I found out that I had to redeploy the gateway, that's when I also conveniently discovered that for any of the configuration changes I was making to be applied, I actually had to redeploy the entire thing.

So after redeploying, everything started to work.